# Azure Cloud Services file system access

Tags: azure, filesystems, remote-access

The "[Best Practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj129545.aspx)" for Azure Cloud Services describes the ugly hacks that make the most of the 1970s-era command line configuration API. (Sorry, I'm not quite old enough to realize the injustice I'm likely doing to computing in that decade.) The debugging approach is to output stdout and stderr to a file in %TEMP%.

My question is how can I access the file? Do I have to Remote Desktop in, or is there a better way, i.e. some sort of remote file system access?

Comment: It's very sad that THESE made their way into "best practices" document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize it's a nuisance to say the least to debug the actual Startup Task of a Cloud Service. I don't particularly enjoy it myself. There is a good way to do it though which takes a lot of the pain out of the process!

I advice you to script this and debug it on the machine itself using Remote Desktop! Once you have the script setup right for whatever it is you need to do on the machine, you simply copy the script into the startup task!

What I'm saying is remove the Startup task and let your Cloud Service launch fully. Then Remote into the instance and debug your script on the box.

I have a more lengthy explanation of this on my blog: [How to set up and debug the Startup Task in a Windows Azure Cloud Service](http://magnusmartensson.com/quick-tip-how-to-set-up-the-startup-task-in-a-windows-azure-cloud-service).

Answer (score 1):

You'll be unable to RD there until the instance has been started. So if you have a problem during startup you're screwed with this approach. Additionally if the VM is returned to Azure (you scale out, then scale in or the VM is considered faulty) you lose all the logs.

The only reliable solution is to use permanent storage such as blob storage. [This post](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/rebranding-part-2-and-upgrading-to-azure-sdk-2-0/) (item 2) shows a decent implementation.

Comment: So if I understand this right, you need to: (1) force the script to report success with `exit /b 0`, so that the web role isn't prevented from starting if there is an error, (2) in the web role, copy the redirected output file to blob storage; and (3) inspect the blob storage to see the results. Is that right?

Comment: @EdwardBrey: Not exactly. If you do (1) your role will have to start in half-initialized state which is rather dumb and hardly a best practice. If you use output redirection you have to upload the file "often enough" which is not reliable. The linked post suggest a much better approach.

Comment: Where does the code in step 2 go? The blog says, "In the startup of our web roles, we have a exception handler that writes any startup problems to blob storage". I thought it went into the web role, but that leaves the problems you mentioned. Do you mean instead that the code goes into a custom C# console app, and use something like `<Task commandLine="Startup.exe">` instead of `Startup.cmd`? It sounds nice, since configuration could be done in C# rather than via command line parameters.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: Yes, you could move your startup code into a separate application or use PowerShell to invoke C# code deirectly. Then you can insert the logging there. Alternatively you can just move the initialization to OnStart() and omit the startup task.

Comment: `OnStart` would be convenient. The problem is maintaining least privilege. I want to disable the idle timeout. While I haven't tried to find the API docs to verify, all the `OnStart`-based samples I've seen show the web role as running as elevated.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: Yes, privileges are a bit of a problem. If your code doesn't run under "regular" context and you really want the least privileges I guess your best bet is to craft that code into a .NET assembly and start it from a startup task using PowerShell. I haven't tried that myself though.